# "Send %variable%" evals my variable before sending it

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script(A) that write another script(B).

The important line in my script(A):

```
InputBox variable, Variable
Send %variable%
```

Then, if i input:

> helloworld{enter}

it will write "helloworld" and insert a new line in my script(B) instead of just writing "{enter}"

How do I force it to write %variable% without interpreting it beforehand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to write another script (scriptB) from scriptA is to use [FileAppend](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileAppend.htm#Example):

```
variable = helloworld

FileAppend,
(
; a line of code
Send %variable%{enter}
; another line of code
)
,C:\scriptB.ahk

Run, edit "C:\scriptB.ahk"
; or:
; Run, C:\scriptB.ahk
```

or

```
InputBox variable, Variable, Enter a variable:
if not ErrorLevel
{
FileAppend,
(
; a line of code
Send %variable%{enter}
; another line of code
)
,C:\scriptB.ahk
Run, edit "C:\scriptB.ahk"
; or:
; Run C:\scriptB.ahk
}
return
```

Comment: Perfect! That is far more efficient than what I was doing.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answer that using FileAppend would be a better method. However, if you truly want to accomplish this using the send command, then you need to use `{raw}` mode. You can read about `{raw}` in the documentation:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm

```
InputBox variable, Variable
Send, {raw}%variable%
```

Comment: I will use the 'FileAppend' solution, but thank you, I didn't know about the {raw} thing. That will probably be helpfull in the future :)